# How can I use AT command of linux from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, email, at-job

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an email queue in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507693/creating-an-email-queue-in-php)

My PHP script is sending hundreds of emails. And I want to set gap between these email sending times as 5 mins. I mean, time tap between each 2 emails should be 5 mins. Like one should be sent at 12:45am, second 12:50am and so on.

For that I have tried from command line:

```
at 08:10am Dec 19
echo "Welcome" | mail -s "Hello world" abc@abc.com
```

So this works fine, mail is sent at 08:10am. But, how can I do the same from PHP?
How can I use AT command of linux from PHP?

Or there is any other easy way?

Comment: There are dozens of questions and examples of this out there - you just need to do some research. Basically, you queue up the emails to-be-sent in a database. Then you have a background process (daemon) that periodically sends out a large batch of emails, and marks them in the database as "sent".  Using `at` is not appropriate here.  For example: [*Creating an email queue in PHP?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507693/creating-an-email-queue-in-php)

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to intigrate database headhache here, I just want to use Linux command only. So please suggest me.

Comment: You will certainly end up with more of a headache if you try and use `at`. It is a hack and a poor design decision, and the application's success will likely follow. But then again, I'm not sure if you care - in that case: [php execute shell command](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+execute+shell+command). The world is at your fingertips. Embrace it.

Answer (score 1):

### To answer your question:

Calling an external program from PHP can be done using many approaches. One of them is [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) and giving it the same complete command string you would've written by hand.

Other functions you can use for this are:

```
popen() // Opens process file pointer
exec() // Execute an external program
system() // Execute an external program and display the output
passthru() //- Execute an external program and display raw output
pcntl_exec() // Executes specified program in current process space
`at` // backtick operator
```

### As a side issue:

Email queueing would be better suited for this indeed - using `at` is a simple hack for what you're trying to accomplish.